# Dotnet new - webpack.js missing

Tags: asp.net, angular, webpack

I downloaded .NET Core SDK version 2.1 and I ran :

```
dotnet new angular -n testAngular
```

... and the project was created successfully.

Then I ran:

```
cd testAngular
dotnet run
```

Which resulted in the following error :

> EXEC : error : Cannot find module
>   C:\Users\OLE\source\repos\testAngular\node_modules\webpack\bin\webpack.js

How can I avoid this error? Adding an empty webpack.js didn't work. Why was webpack.js not added, when running dotnet new ? What should I put in it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your node_modules library doesn't have webpack installed. 
Could be two reasons

1. Your package.json includes webpack, and you never installed it.
   Inside testAngular run

`npm install`

2. Your project doesn't include webpack.
   Inside testAngular run

`npm install webpack -D`

If you can't run npm, then install it from [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Comment: Thanks, that works. But I still find it strange that dotnet run installs something that doesn't work out of the box.

Comment: @OleEHDufour, not sure how you acquired .net framework with angular. But node_modules directories can become very heavy size-wise. Enough to make it common for developers to add it to .gitignore list so it doesn't get checked in. That's why it's very common when cloning existing repositories, to have to need to run `npm install`.